# Compilation issue with Sed 4.2.1

Tags: linux, compilation, sed, gawk, linux-from-scratch

When I try to launch the ./configure command of Sed I get:

```
gawk: ./conf1dkaC9/subs.awk:3: fatal error: internal error
./config.status: line 1409:  7676 Done                    eval sed \"\$ac_sed_extra\" "$ac_file_inputs"
  7677 Aborted                 (core dumped) | $AWK -f "$tmp/subs.awk" > $tmp/out
  config.status: error: could not create bootstrap.sh
```

I'm actually following the LFS 7.1 book. Last night I stopped my work at the chapter dealing with Sed compilation and thus, I have shut down my PC. When I turned it on this morning, every ./configure command of every package failed and returned the message above. The same packages had no problems with ./configure before I shut down my PC. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with tmp files due to many files created in tmp. You can try to clean your `/tmp` directory.

Comment: There is no risk to use: sudo rm -vfR /tmp/*  to clear the tmp folder?

Comment: also check this out: http://nixcraft.com/slackware/15193-unable-create-files-change-perms-tmp.html

Comment: Well, it's ok I removed all the files in the tmp folder but the error stand still.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `gawk` binary is broken. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: I tried but when I launch the ./configure of gawk... I let you guess what happen lol... It's the egg and chicken story.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if an executable in the temporary tool chain is broken. As the user lfs has /tools/bin in its PATH before /usr/bin and /bin it uses that executable allready. To recover, try removing the broken executable from /tools/bin and repeat the step where it is installed.

My guess which executable is broken is sed, but it might also be gawk (as the previous answer suggests).